# Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints. while loading data from a DB2 SP

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, ado.net, oledb

I am trying to load data into a datatable and then process them to load inside a .csv file but when i am doing datatable.load() and executing the command inside it(which calls an IBMi DB2 stored proc-runs fine in ibmi client access solution), after 2 mins it fails with the below error-

Kindly help on how can i identify where the error is or how to overcome this issue.(Tried dt.clear/dt.rows.clear/dt.column.clear but no luck)

[image]

Comment: Try reading the data by row so you can see what each one contains.

Comment: @user18387401 do i need to define all the columns returned by the sp? Can u give a link or something how to do it

Comment: I didn't say anything about defining columns. I said read the data row by row. There are plenty of examples of reading data using a data reader. You can find them just as easily as I can. You might also consider reading the documentation for the `OleDbDataReader` class. ALWAYS read the documentation for new types and members.

Comment: tried this with datareader and it worked fine . The issue is i am getting data from Sp which returns 6 columns and i need to add a new column which is excatly as same column as 6th but the date is formed and i can't add a column if i use datareader object as its unidirectional

Comment: I didn't tell you not to use a `DataTable`. Please pay attention. Read the data row by row so that you can see what it contains, as I said in the first place. When you know what data is there, you'll be able to work out why it's violating one of those constraints. You can then make the appropriate change(s) and go back to loading the data into the `DataTable`.